# How can I get notified when the property page changes in view class

Tags: c++, mfc

I have a property sheet (`CPropertySheet` derived class) and its pages (`CPropertyPage` derived class) in `CView` derived view class. I need to get notice at `CView` derived  class when the property page changes.

In my case, handling the `PSN_SETACTIVE` notification will not work.

[image]

The problem is by changing the page I need to update the data in the page from one resource. If that resource is not active then I need to close the view and restart the view again.

Answer (score 4):

`CPropertySheet` does not receive information about tab changes.

`PSN_SETACTIVE` and `PSN_KILLACTIVE` is sent to `CPropertyPage` instead. You have to handle these messages in each PropertyPage when tab is selected/un-selected.

In MFC you can handle this as follows:

```
class CMyPropertyPage: public CPropertyPage
{
    BOOL OnSetActive();
    BOOL OnKillActive();
    ...
};

BOOL CMyPropertyPage:OnSetActive()
{
    BOOL res = CPropertyPage::OnSetActive();
    TRACE("CMyPropertyPage tab selected\n");
    return res;
}   

BOOL CMyPropertyPage:OnKillActive()
{
    BOOL res = CPropertyPage::OnKillActive();
    TRACE("CMyPropertyPage tab unselected\n");
    return res;
}
```

See also:
[WinAPI property sheet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774538(v=vs.85).aspx#Adding_and_Removing_)
[CPropertyPage::OnSetActive](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5zd196y3.aspx)

To send notification to `CMyView`, you will have to find the handle to your target and pass the message.

Comment: PSN_SETACTIVE can be handled in CPropertySheet also. Your solution is correct. But in certain case it is not working. For example while handling this method, I cannot modify( delete or add pages to the property sheet and I can't destroy the current frames also.) pages or fram.

Comment: You have completely changed your question in such a way that it makes my answer look stupid. You write that you don't want `PSN_SETACTIVE` **after** I gave an answer to use `PSN_SETACTIVE`. You don't even mention that you edited your question. You have added other weird requirements along with documentation explaining why `PSN_SETACTIVE` is wrong.

Comment: your solution is  helpful to me  but it is not suited for my problem